# What is the difference between inline scripts and first & third party scripts?

Tags: browser, javascript, adblock, addons, ublock

I use [uBlock₀](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/) as my ad-blocker. It has 3 options for dynamic filtering, namely,

- inline scripts
- first party scripts
- third party scripts

[image]

What is the difference between inline scripts and first & third party scripts?

I found a wiki page on [Dynamic Filtering](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering) but it doesn't explain the difference.

I also tried to see if there is a difference between

- only inline scripts block (1st party script allowed) and
- only first party scripts block (inline script allowed)

on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), and found that site functions like "**INBOX**" and "**ACHIEVEMENTS**" don't work when inline scripts are blocked, but work even when 1st party scripts are blocked. (see image below)

Can you explain this behaviour?

[image: SuperUser's INBOX feature]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline scripts are scripts written in an <script> block within the HTML page that you load. You can see them by pressing F12 in Firefox, Chrome, IE and Edge.

First-party scripts are scripts that are included in separate .js files but are located on the same domain name as the HTML page. For example, if you are browsing superuser.com, all scripts under superuser.com domain are first-party scripts.

Third-party scripts are scripts that are included in separate .js files but are located on another domain. For example, if you are browsing superuser.com, all scripts under any domain other than superuser.com are third-party.

These options are situational tools. Arbitrary use of them results in impaired web browsing experience. Use them sparingly and be sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: what are the differences between **3rd-party** and **3rd-party scripts**? It is explained [here](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/02/08/ublocks-all-and-third-party-deny-modes-block-requests-by-default/) but I still can't figure out